# I can't find out how to stop this hex to byte using ASCII representations of hex values

Tags: python, serial-port, modbus

I am working with a program which needs to output this command to the Serial port:

`b'\x01\x10\x00\x08\x00\x02\x04\x00\x00\x16\x43\xe7\xf5'`

It uses the following function to take in a preformatted command and package it up before sending it on the serial line.

```
def pumpSendData(command):
    temp = command.split("%")
    
    if(temp[0] == "SETFLOW"):
        #data = (str(command_dict[temp[0]])).format(temp[1])
        data = "01 10 00 08 00 02 04 00 00 16 43 E7 F5"
    else:
        data = command_dict[str(temp[0])]
    
    print(data)
    data = data.replace(" ","")
    print(data)
    data_bytes = bytes.fromhex(data)
    print(data_bytes)
    
    try:
        PMPser.open()
    except:
        PMPser.close()
        PMPser.open()
    
    PMPser.write(data_bytes)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    response = PMPser.readline()
    response_str = ' '.join([format(res, '02X') for res in response])
    PMPser.close()
    
    print(response_str)
    
    return response_str
```

Given the expectation of this function I can't seem to figure out why it is converting the 4th value byte hex byte into the ascii representation and concatenating it to the value previous to it, instead of just making another partition on the serial string. Below is an example of the terminal output.

```
0110000800020400001643E7F5
b'\x01\x10\x00\x08\x00\x02\x04\x00\x00\x16C\xe7\xf5'
```

Let me know if anyone has any ideas or questions about the issue.

I have tried changing how I preformat the command but it doesn't seem to change anything. I'm not sure how to stop `bytes.fromhex(data)` from using the ascii representation of numbers.

Comment: You have shown code which has: `print(data_bytes)` followed later by `PMPser.write(data_bytes)`. Does the device to which you are sending `data_bytes` accept the right data? I would ignore the output of `print(data_bytes)`, since python easily confuses programmers in a bid to be "helpful".

Comment: Using `print(data_bytes.hex())` maybe more helpful.